# Get all children of android.widget.ListView with UIAutomator

Tags: android, listview, android-testing, android-uiautomator

Is it possible to get all the child items of ListView with UIAutomator? The issue I am facing is that `listView.getChildCount();` only returns the number of children in the view. I tried to scroll and add the count but it is not working reliably.

```
UiScrollable listView = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(
        true).className("android.widget.ListView"));
listView.setAsVerticalList();

listView.flingToBeginning(100);

int count = listView.getChildCount();
listView.scrollForward();
count += listView.getChildCount();
Log.d("STATE", "COUNT: " + count);
```

Is there any reliable way to get all the children of ListView when scrolling is needed?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, Uiautomator is only able to see the objects that are currently on the screen...if you want to scroll to a specific object in the list, you can do it like this:

> listView.scrollIntoView(uiobjectYourLookingFor);

or this:

```
UiObject uiObjectYouWant = listView.getChild(newUiSelector().resourceId(com.yourappname:id/yourId");
```

Both of these will scroll to the object you specify